# Get text not contained in tags htmlagilitypack vb.net

Tags: html, html-agility-pack, vb.net-2010

I simply would like to know how can I get text from websites (with vb.net) that are not between HTML tags (not like this, for example, `<b> hello </b>`). I know that I can use HtmlAgilityPack and I have been reading and reading but I don't get nothing that can help me.

I need to extract text like this:

```
<td colspan="2">
<b>Some text:</b>
I need to extract this text
<a href="#">Some text</a>
<a href="#">Some text 2</a>
...
```

This is from a website that needs login first so I can't give you the URL. I would need to extract this from a website, not for HTML file or var String.

Comment: Why don't you try to read the `innerHTML` from the `<td>` tag? I mean, everything is contained in something, at least in the `<body>` tag. Please provide more information on the things you have already tried, if you still need an answer. Otherwise post the answer yourself.

Comment: `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection Nodes = Doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td/a");` now you can loop with foreach to get all immeadiate childrens of td element. post full html for further details.